# How to get the cardId from contactId,orderId or InvoiceId from infusionsoft api?

Tags: php

Actually I need to find the cardId (or last four digits of his card) from an already order done by a user. I have his contact id, orderid,product id and invoice. Also how to stop recurring payment from an existing order via infusionsoft api?

Comment: What did you try? We can only help you if we see your code, we can't guess your code.

Answer (score 0):

We can get the credit card details from infusionsoft by using contact id, for this we have to query the "CreditCard" table. like:-

```
 $returnFields = array('Id','last4','CardType','ExpirationMonth','NameOnCard');
 $query = array('ContactId' => $contactID);
 $cardDetails = $this->dsQuery("CreditCard", 1, 0, $query, $returnFields);
```